# How to clean the inline keyboard in aiogram Telegram?

Tags: telegram, aiogram

My goal is to create as many buttons as amounts of users with their names (SQL) , but problem is i don't know the name of the function that cleans keyboard every time I call it

```
async def set_kb():
    # here should be function
    for i in db_show_players():
        in_group_kb_players.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(i[0]), callback_data=i[1]))
```

I tried .clean() but it didn't work

Comment: Hello. Can you specify why do you need to clean the keyboard? Haven't you tried just creating a new one? You're not forced to use one markup every time.

Comment: The number of buttons are directly depend on number of users in data base. When user write command /players my code firstly runs some function which reads the data base and creates buttons for each user's name and then it returns keyboard. But when you call the function at the second time you will face duplicated buttons. In fact we can create new keyboard every time but in order to escape memory leak we need to delete that anyway

Answer (score 1):

I solved that.
solution was simple damn..
there is no function that clears the keyboard so the variable should be local. in my case i imported that into other module which created this bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
await message.answer(content["Text"], reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```